# Let Matlab continue without waiting for a result

Tags: matlab

I have the following question: How do I tell Matlab that it should not wait for the results of a function? Is there a way other than threads?

My problem: I have a function A that is called by a Timer every few seconds. If a specific event is met, another function B is called inside function A. Function B opens a Batch File.
I want function A to go on without waiting for function B to end. Is there a way to easily do it?

I'm sorry if this question was already asked, but I couldn't find a satisfying answer. Please also excuse my bad english.

I would like to thank everyone who answers for their help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your function B, just call the batch file with a `&` at the end of the line.

For example:

```
!mybatch.bat &
```

This will run the file `mybatch.bat` in background mode and will return execution to Matlab immediately after the call.

or if you prefer the complete form:

```
[status, result] = system('mybatch.bat &')
```

But in this case it is a bit useless, since the system call `mybatch` in the background, the `result` variable is always empty and `status` is always `0` (whether a file `mybatch.bat` was found and executed or not)

---

edit: That is the quick trick in case it is only the batch file execution which is slowing down your program.

If you have more matlab instructions in function B and you really need function A to go on without waiting, you will have to set up a listener object with function B as a callback. Then in your function A, trigger the event (which will activate the listener and call function B).