# automatic response to prompt inside loop

Tags: matlab, input

I have a function which requires to input a letter every time it runs:

```
Do you want to exclude the warnings from the list? Enter y/n
```

I want to make a loop, In which the answer "y" will be executed automatically whenever asked. Is it possible?

EDIT: The function is called by program and it is in a format I cant open - .mexw64, .mexw32, .mexmaci64, .mexglx, .mexa64

Comment: It should be possible. Show us the function structure, and how it calls for input.

Comment: See if [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27933270/2586922) helps