# How to send commands to command window programmatically in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, shell, command-line, command, conda

In matlab I can change to another shell by the bang (!) Notation.

**Example:**
I enter a conda Environment in MATLAB by the following command:

```
!cmd '"%windir%\System32\cmd.exe" /K ""C:\Program Files\Anaconda3\Scripts\activate_<conda-env-name>.bat" "C:\Program Files\Anaconda3""'
```

My MATLAB Command window then Displays following:

```
(<conda-env-name>) U:\some_starting_path>
```

*Now, is there a way to send commands to this newly entered shell in a programmatic way, so that that command is evaluated in that very shell's syntax and not as a MATLAB-command?*
For example, how can I write code that will execute a Python command without needing to enter it manually into the command line?

Comment: Just for clarification: when you add `!` to any command window line, you are basically telling MATLAB to run whatever comes next in the *System command line*. So they are not valid MATLAB lines, they are valid OS lines.

Comment: [Call Python from MATLAB](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_external/call-python-from-matlab.html)

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27933270/2586922) may be useful

Answer (score 1):

Not using the `!` command or `system()`. Those are "one and done" functions.

But you can use Java's [`java.lang.Process` API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Process.html) from within Matlab to control and interact with an ongoing process.

```matlab
function control_another_process

pb = java.lang.ProcessBuilder(["myCommand", "myArg1", "myArg2"]);
proc = pb.start;  % now proc is a java.lang.Process object
stdin = proc.getOutputStream;  % Here's how you send commands to the process
stdout = proc.getInputStream;  % And here's how you get its output
stderr = proc.getErrorStream;

% ... now do stuff with the process ...

end
```

You can use this with a shell, with `python`, or any other command.

Here's a Matlab class that wraps up the Java code to make it convenient to work with in Matlab: https://github.com/apjanke/janklab/blob/master/Mcode/classes/%2Bjl/%2Butil/Process.m